# PMD plugin for gradle

Tags: gradle, pmd, build.gradle

I am using intellij idea with gradle for developing a java project.

I have applied pmd plugin at subprojects level in build.gradle file.

When i run the commoand 'gradlew check' on command line, i get pmd warnings only for one module. When i fix those and run the command again, i get pmd warnings for next module.

I want to list all pmd warnings across all modules.

I tried to put the line 'apply plugin: pmd' under allprojects section in build.gradle file.

Any suggestion how could i achieve it?

Thanks,
Vijay Bhore

Comment: Set [ignoreFailures](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html) to true

Comment: adding pmd.ignoreFailures = true in project build.gradle helped. Thanks!